# How can i speed up populating a table in Microsoft Word using powershell?

Tags: powershell, ms-word, powershell-3.0

I have a powershell script that writes to a large table in a word document, but it is slow. I was wondering if there was a way I could speed it up or is there a more efficient way to do it. I'm only writing to the last row of the table

```
$wd = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$wd.Visible = $false
$doc = $wd.Documents.Open("test.doc"  )
$iTable = $doc.Tables.Item(1)
$r = $iTable.Rows.Count
$c = 1

#write to doc
$iTable.Cell($r, $c).Range.Text=$int
$iTable.Cell($r, $c+1).Range.Text=(get-item env:$x).Value
$iTable.Cell($r, $c+2).Range.Text=$lob.ToUpper()
$iTable.Cell($r, $c+3).Range.Text=$line
```

Comment: You can populate a row with tab limited text from the clipboard, but it's not really nice:$iTable.Rows.Item($r).Select()
$int,$env:x,$lob.ToUpper(),$line -join "`t" | clip
$wd.Selection.Paste()

Comment: For performance gains I would experiment with (a) create the table first then populate, or add rows in large chunks then remove excess at the end, (b) write the data with HTML table tags to a text file, then use InsertFile - you will need to deal with special characters, (c) build the table as a Word 2003 XML or Flat OPC XML document (cf. (b), but harder) in a string, then use .InsertXML to insert the string. For (b) and (c) it would probably be simpler to apply formatting post-insert.

Comment: Dirk, that line does not work. I get an error saying Unexpected token 'int' in expression or statement.

Comment: you need to put a semicolon or line break after the select() :$iTable.Rows.Item($r).Select(); $int,$env:x,$lob.ToUpper(),$line -join "`t" | clip $wd.Selection.Paste()